# Missing } inserted Latex

Tags: latex

```
\begin{equation}
\tau _{2}(r_{0})=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}}\frac{r_{0}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3} \\ 
\frac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}}\frac{r_{c}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3} 
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}
```

Basically I am wrtting an equation in Latex which should be displayed in the form[image]

But Latex reports error "Missing } inserted" on the third line. What is the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Without a minimal working example (MWE), the exact reason is hard to tell. When I copy paste this to a document using `article` as document class and load the `amsmath` package, this works. Probably you didn't load `amsmath`? See my answer for a simple way to create cases in an equation.

Answer (score 2):

The `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package exists for exactly this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \tau_{2}(r_{0}) = 
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}}\frac{r_{0}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3} \\ 
        \frac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}}\frac{r_{c}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3} 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This also makes it easy to add description, e.g.

```
\begin{equation}
    \tau_{2}(r_{0}) = 
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}}\frac{r_{0}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3} & \text{if } c = 0\\ 
        \frac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}}\frac{r_{c}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3} & \text{otherwise} \\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the equation and this works. Not sure if it is what you were trying to achieve

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\[
    \tau _{2}(r_{0})= \left[
         \begin{array}{ccc}
         \dfrac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}} & \dfrac{r_{0}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3}\\
         \dfrac{R^{d}-r_{c}^{d}}{D_{1}} & \dfrac{r_{c}^{-1}-a^{-1}}{-3}
        \end{array}
    \right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, though this is not what I want, it inspired me. I modified something and it works now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Damien If it helped you that's great. You can modify this answer or add a new one so anyone who comes on this site knows which is the right answer

Comment: Well I found that the answers given by the guys above are better than what I came up with, more neat.